# Why does the exp(x) not work in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, pdftex

I am currently working on a paper and require an equation with e^x. I tried using the suggested layout of $\exp(x)$ but my output only shows an equation with exp(x) in the PDF output. Is there something that I am doing wrong is is there a specific package I need to use?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Your question is not very clear: does by any chance `$e^{x}$` do what you want?

Comment: Yes it does but I am confused why the alternative notation would not work since I have ensured that I did not make any mistakes in writing the $\exp(x)$

Comment: The alternative notation is just that: there is no “translation” of `\exp(x)` into `e^{x}`. There are cases where the former notation is preferable to the latter.

Comment: The input `\exp(x)` is specifically meant to generate the word “exp” (in upright font), a left parenthesis, an “x” in math italic font, and a closing parenthesis.  In LaTeX, to add a superscript to something you must use the `^` notation.  I advise you not to try to write anything in LaTeX without having previously read an introductory guide (at least).

Comment: As already mentioned, `\exp` is an alternative notation to `e^{...}` that users should know. Sadly not everyone does. Consider `\[\exp\biggl(\int_0^1 fdx\biggr) \qquad e^{\int_0^1 fdx} \]` which of these are more redable? There are many examples of this where there are a short notation for simple input, and a companion notation for complicated input.

Comment: @GuM I have written in LaTex numerous times already but I have not encountered an equation where I needed to use e^x. Thanks for pointing out the differences and my misunderstanding.

Comment: LaTeX just deals with symbols, not the meaning behind them. Both exp(x) and e^x denote the same mathematical function, but the former is written in Latex with `\exp(x)` and the latter with `e^x`.

Comment: @TimothySusanto: Well, `e^x` is in no way different from `x^2`, as far as (La)TeX is concerned… :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood what you have been told.

`\exp(x)` is not an alternative to `e^{x}` in LaTeX, exp(*x*) is an alternative to *e*<sup>*x*</sup> in maths and physics etc.

The exp(*x*) notation is useful where *x* is some large or complicated expression, e.g.:

```
\[
  \exp\biggl(\, \sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac{1}{n} \biggr)
\]
```

[image]

Which I certainly think is a big improvement over:

```
\[
  e^{\sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac{1}{n}}
\]
```

[image]

The *e*<sup>*x*</sup> notation is useful where *x* is something nice and small, like, well:

```
\[
  e^{x}
\]
```

[image]

So LaTeX supports both, `\exp(x)` for exp(*x*) and `e^{x}` for *e*<sup>*x*</sup>. `\exp(x)` is not a LaTeX shorthand (longhand?) for `e^{x}` = *e*<sup>*x*</sup>.

Comment: A further improvement is adding `\,` between `\biggl(` and `\sum`: try and judge for yourself.

Comment: @egreg I wanted to do that, but I didn't trust my own judgement, I'll make the change, thanks!

Comment: I recommend `\,` also when a radical is followed by a parenthesis with a similar height, for instance (and in other cases).

Comment: Good obs @egreg!! Do you know about automatic spacing? Why `\,` but `\;` no? Is subjective?

Comment: @manooooh `\;` is too much; a thin space is usually the best.